# python can't see packages from pip3

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, pip

I have put pyspark on kali.  Just getting into python for work.  Python works, pip3 lists a ton of packages but pyspark import fails.  Any hints?

```
root@uname -v
#1 SMP Debian 5.10.13-1kali1 (2021-02-08)
root@:~# pip3 -V
pip 20.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9)
root@:~# python3 -V
Python 3.9.1+
```

Tutorials show running from vim and command line, but want to run from pycharm community edition 2020.2 which I have installed successfully. Pycharm is not happy with the env vars tutorial had me setup.

Pycharm error message:
The use of Java options environment variables detected. Such variables override IDE configuration files (*.vmoptions) and may cause performance and stability issues. Please consider deleting these variables: _JAVA_OPTIONS.

This is because I updated by .bashrc file at the end of it as shown...

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin 

export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.9
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.9
```

here is some extra info..

```
root@:/usr/lib# ls | grep python
libpyglib-2.0-python2.7.so.0
libpyglib-2.0-python2.7.so.0.0.0
python2.6
python2.7
python3
python3.7
python3.9
```

I am aware that pycharm will need some tweaking, but that is also part of my questions here.  I put my interpreter paths below, knowing they will need updating, but never having done that before.

```
file:///usr/lib/python3.7
file:///usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
file:///root/PycharmProjects/BeginningApacheSparkUsingDatabricksBook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Comment: See this link and see if it helps `https://kaizen.itversity.com/setup-spark-development-environment-pycharm-and-python/`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the python `site-packages` path is not present under `$PYTHONPATH`. Try to add the path to the above environment variable

## Macos -

```
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH"
```